# BootsFaces tag auto completion shows duplicate properties style-class and styleClass

Tags: jsf, ide, code-completion, bootsfaces

Check the below screeshot,

[image]

why is there for instance `style-class` and `styleClass`?

I am using bootsfaces 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both versions are identical. Most web designers prefer the `style-class` version for their CSS class names. CamelCase is a tradition of Java developers. We felt that it looks odd to use CamelCase among all these boot-strap-css-classes. So we decided to implement the hyphen version as an alternative to the traditional CamelCase attribute names of JSF. We hope that it allows you to write files that look nicer, and maybe the attribute names are easier to memorize.